# jQuery - Get URL of iframe AFTER redirection on same domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Using Jquery, how can I get the URL of an iframe after redirection has occurred to a URL in the same domain?

Comment: What kind of redirection? Where is the jQuery instance running?

Comment: I think it's a redirect with a location header. What do you mean with your second question? I'm not running this script on the same site. I just need to find out the URL which it's redirecting to programatically.

Answer (score 8):

The suggestion from sunn0 should work with this slight amendment.

```
 $("#iframeid").load(function(){
    alert(this.contentWindow.location);
 });
```

Comment: @confiq are you loading a page on the same domain in the iframe? You can only inspect the location on the same domain.

Comment: Yeah, I've figure out that I can't access `.location` property if it's not same domain/port.